# Sad story about killing sentient, but dangerous, beings brought by a smuggler

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this very sad short fiction (novelette rather than short story, I think) more than 20 years ago, in a collection. It might be older. It left me a very sad feeling.

It takes place on a planet colonized by earthlings. At least one area is sparsely populated, at the foot of mountains. Not sure whether it was just barely more peopled elsewhere, or whether there was a large population further away. A small group of sentient, intelligent but very dangerous beings reach this planet (and this area) by accident. IIRC, some smuggler of  wild animals took them from their home planet to sell them in zoos somewhere but had to stop early because his spaceship had technical issues, which also had the escape of these beings as a consequence.

One party of humans is attacked, most are killed, the surviving ones tell a frightening story. Then the smuggler appears, confirms the existence of these beings, and warns that they are both aggressive and prolific and that humans must kill them at all price.

Most of the story is the chase. Lots of casualties on both sides. Finally, the POV character, a human, kills the last survivors of these beings, because he understands that they represent a real danger. But he feels very bad about it, and so did I. They really were no animals, he had concluded during the chase, they were almost human, but too dangerous and prolific to be left in the wild.

One characteristic of the story is the style. It looks like transcribed spoken language, rather than a written text. A lot of orthographic mistakes most probably represent a heavy **accent** rather than **ignorance** : for instance "of" for "have", lots of wrong vowels, but no wrong spellings for words where the correct and the wrong spelling sound exactly alike.  I remember the word "bear" was used for the animal (not these beings, and probably not the bear from Earth, but rather some native bear-looking wild creature, but one that the humans could live with and did not need to exterminate - IIRC, they had dogs large enough to keep these bears away), and was never spelled "bare", for instance, something like that I would have remembered.

---

EDIT

A suggestion by bob1 below about "Novice" reminded me that in the "frontier" area  where the events take place there are no (human) women.

Comment: Some elements of *Novice* by James Schmitz, but POV is wrong and the Crest Cats don't get killed in that, other than early on as "sport" animals.

Comment: The ending is reminiscent of Death of a Hunter by Shaara but in that story the "beasts" were indigenous IIRC.

Comment: @bob1 There are not enough elements for me to judge. Can you give me a link where I could get a synopsis ?

Comment: @Alfred yeah, that's why I didn't write it up. I'll be interested in reading what it turns out to be.

Comment: @OrganicMarble In this story the "beasts" were not indigenous, killing the last one of the small party the smuggler has inadvertently brought was the end. Can you give me a link where I could get a synopsis ?

Comment: @Alfred https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/193677/28516

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for the  link. Definitely not it. The humans settled a world without humanoids. There were native "bears", able to sometimes kill settlers but not presenting an existential threat. The very prolific (according to the smuggler, but why would he lie ?) newcomers were such a threat.

Comment: @Alfred [Novice @ Project Gutenberg](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/30458)

Comment: @Bob1 Thank you but it is not my story:  there were no women in that "frontier" area